# Passing two arguments (dates) from C# to a python script

Tags: c#, python

I am using Visual Studio 12 to create forms utilizing C#. I have been successful in passing one argument from C# to python. I am not using Iron python. The new application I am working on needs to pass two arguments to python. Both arguments are dates that the user picks.
[image]

This is my code to capture the arguments and pass them to Python.

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbegin = PublicVars.g_begindate;
        dend = PublicVars.g_enddate;

        CallPython python = new   CallPython(@"C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe");
           python.Run_Script(@"\\gisdb01\gis\tools\Python\TA_Report\Update_4_Road.pyc", dbegin dend);

        this.Close();
    }

    private void dateTimePickerBegin_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PublicVars.g_begindate = dateTimePickerBegin.Text;
    }

    private void dateTimePickerEnd_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PublicVars.g_enddate = dateTimePickerEnd.Text;
```

What happens is the error highlights '**dend**' and gives me "**) expected**". I have tried adding )'s and commas between dbegin and dend but cannot seem to get this to work.

This is the code I use to Call Python:

```
namespace Advisory_Application
{
    class CallPython
    {
        string pythonLocationString;
        public CallPython(string pythonLocation)
        {
            pythonLocationString = pythonLocation;
        }

        public void Run_Script(string scriptPathName, string arguments)
        {
            int ExitCode;
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processStartInfo.FileName = pythonLocationString;
            processStartInfo.Arguments = scriptPathName;
            processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            processStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            Process updateProcess = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
            updateProcess.WaitForExit();
            ExitCode = updateProcess.ExitCode;
            updateProcess.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change `RunScript` to accept an array of arguments with the `params` modifier.

```
public void Run_Script(string scriptPathName, params object[] arguments)
```

Then change this line

```
processStartInfo.Arguments = scriptPathName;
```

to this

```
processStartInfo.Arguments = scriptPathName + " " + string.Join(" ", arguments);
```

So it will include the script name and the parameters you are passing to it.
Then call it like this (the `params` means you can just list off as many parameters as you want.

```
python.Run_Script(@"\\gisdb01\gis\tools\Python\TA_Report\Update_4_Road.pyc", dbegin, dend);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are passing two variables in only one parameters. If your function accepts more parameters you can add a simple comma between them.

```
CallPython python = new   CallPython(@"C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.3\python.exe");
          python.Run_Script(@"\\gisdb01\gis\tools\Python\TA_Report\Update_4_Road.pyc", dbegin, dend);
```

If you can only pass one parameter, I suggest to concatenate dbegin and dend variables in a single variable, and later on in python side separate them again in two different vars if you need it.

If dbegin and dend are strings you can do it as follows.

```
dconcatenated = dbegin + dend;
```

If they are another type you can transform them to string and after that concatenate them.